# Hyperlink text to another list xslt

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, data-view-web-part, xslt

Anyone have ideas how I can link a text in another list.

I have a one list(A) which contains items i want to display. I want to link to an article in list (B) Pages library  using xslt dataview.

Any ideas please.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that List A contains something like a Lookup column to List B, you could use a linked datasource. I wrote some [instructions for SharePoint 2007](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/11/17/merged-data-sources-for-the-dataview-web-part/), though you'd want a 'Join' not a 'Merge'. I think the approach is the same in 2010, though [the UI is different](http://www.rightpoint.com/community/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2011/03/17/where-d-my-linked-data-source-go-on-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx).